# How are hashcode() and compareTo() related?

Tags: java, hashcode, compareto

I've found this class definition:

```
class TwoTuple28<A,B> implements Comparable {
  // ...
  public int hashCode() {
    int result = 17;
    result = result * 37 + first.hashCode();
    result = result * 37 + second.hashCode();
    return result;
  }
  public int compareTo(Object o) {
    if(!(o instanceof TwoTuple28)) throw new ClassCastException();
    TwoTuple28 t = (TwoTuple28)o;
    return (this.hashCode() - t.hashCode() < 0) ? -1 : 
    ((this.hashCode() - t.hashCode() > 0 ? 1 : 0));
}
```

Could you please explain me, why did the developer use hashCode() into compareTo()? How are they related? Isn't it a wrong way?

Comment: They aren't related. That's the wrong way to do it.

Comment: I think that code you found is pretty horrible.

Answer (score 1):

In short, this is a very bad idea. It sort of works, but will fail in ways which would be easily missed in testing.

The purpose of comparison is to say when one object is higher, lower or equal to another. When two object are equal, they are a considered a duplicate for ConcurrentSkipListMap, TreeMap and TreeSet which means that two objects with the same hashCode in this case would be considered a duplicate and ignored.  How likely is two object with the same hashCode? if you have a collection of tens of thousands, you are highly likely to have duplicates even with a much better hashCode than the one above.

BTW, HashMap and HashSet now use `compareTo` when there are collisions and even in these collections a poor compareTo can mean keys/elements disappear.

The safe way to implement this method is to assume the first and second fields are Comparable, otherwise you don't have a basis to compare them.

---

On a related note, a puzzle for you.

Write a program to print strings of words which have a `hashCode()` of `0`.  You should be able to generate thousands in less than ten seconds.